# AccountFeed Returning null, GA API

Tags: c#, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

trying to test out this account feed from Google Analytics API in C#.

anyway, here is the code example, for some reason, the **accountFeed** stays null, even though I provide the account information. Not sure if this is a version problem.

```
public AccountFeedExample()
    {

      // Configure GA API.
      AnalyticsService asv = new AnalyticsService("gaExportAPI_acctSample_v2.0");

      // Client Login Authorization.
      asv.setUserCredentials(CLIENT_USERNAME, CLIENT_PASS);

      // GA Account Feed query uri.

      AccountQuery query = new AccountQuery("https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/accounts");

//Tried to manually insert the date info, still shows the accountfeed as null.
      query.StartDate = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
      query.EndDate = new DateTime(2014, 1, 14);

      // Send our request to the Analytics API and wait for the results to
      // come back.
      accountFeed = asv.Query(query);
    }
```

Tried to re-write it in this format:
http://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/accounts/1234/webproperties/UA-1234-2/profiles

from the following link:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v2/mgmtFeedReference#accountFeed

doesn't seem to work, not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing the hole authentication process in that.  You need to log with Oauth2 before you can to access anything.  Second problem is that the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/) is for returning information about the accounts and doesn't require dates.  The [core reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) that actually returns the data and requires dates.

Foremost you should be using the V3 client lib not V2, while V3 might still be in beta its a lot easer to use.   The nugget command for the libs you need is:

```
pm>Install-Package Google.Apis.Analytics.v3 -Pre
```

I have a tutorial that walks you though how to access [Google Analtyics with C#](http://www.daimto.com/google-analytics-api-v3-with-c/).

Let me know if I can be of any more help.

Comment: just skimmed through your tutorial, its exactly what I needed, and i got the nuget install as well. Thank you, giving you check and the +1 for the tut.